# Twitter API Authentication

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to pick up iOS development. I'm creating an app for myself (will not release) that, dumbed down, takes a query input from the user and searches through twitter using that query.

I can use a `UIWebView`, but I want to use Twitter's REST API instead, to get familiar with how APIs work. However, I can't get it to work because twitter's API requires authentication (something which I seldom understand).

How does authentication work, and can I authenticate an app which I will use for myself?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter uses OAUTH2. Basically it is something like this:

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+

                 Figure 1: Abstract Protocol Flow
```

> The abstract OAuth 2.0 flow illustrated in Figure 1 describes the
> interaction between the four roles and includes the following steps:
>
> (A)  The client requests authorization from the resource owner.
> The
> authorization request can be made directly to the resource owner
> (as shown), or preferably indirectly via the authorization
> server as an intermediary.
>
> (B)  The client receives an authorization grant, which is a
> credential representing the resource owner's authorization,
> expressed using one of four grant types defined in this
> specification or using an extension grant type.  The
> authorization grant type depends on the method used by the
> client to request authorization and the types supported by the
> authorization server.
>
> (C)  The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
> authorization server and presenting the authorization grant.
>
> (D)  The authorization server authenticates the client and
> validates
> the authorization grant, and if valid, issues an access token.

Above is an exceprt from [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Please read through [this](http://oauth.net/2/) . There are already sample code in various languages there. And here is a [sample code for iphone/ipad](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Client)